# How can I play a mp3 file via adb command with google play music on android kitkat 4.4.4?

Tags: android, automation, adb

I just have tried the old method of start to play a .mp3 file with adb command.

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity -d /sdcard/Music/abc.mp3
```

But currently it does not work. Could any one help to check if there are any updated ways to do so?

Comment: And I also have tried `adb shell am start -n com.google.android.music/com.android.music.activitymanagement.TopLevelActivity -d /sdcard/Music/abc.mp3` since I found the sub-activity name has been changed. but could only start the activity, not able to play.

Comment: I also tried `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.View -d "file:///sdcard/Music/abc.mp3" -n "com.google.android.music/com.android.music.activitymanagement.TopLevelActivity"`, still does not works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue resolved by using command such as:

(file path: **/storage/sdcard0/test.wav**)

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/sdcard0/test.wav -t audio/wav
```

(file path: **/storage/emulated/0/test.wav**)

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/emulated/0/test.wav -t audio/wav
```

Comment: how bout stopping playback?

Answer (score 4):

Start Play:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/emulated/0/test.wav  -t audio/wav
```

To Close the Player:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

To Stop the Player:

```
adb shell input keyevent 127
```

Pause/resume:

```
adb shell input keyevent 85
```