# How to play one audio file in android using adb command?

Tags: android, adb

I am having one android target.
I have some audio file in mnt/sdcard0.
How can I play through adb command?
Music player application is already installed in the target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I play a mp3 file via adb commnad with google play musc on android kitkat 4.4.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083848/how-can-i-play-a-mp3-file-via-adb-commnad-with-google-play-musc-on-android-kitka)

Answer (score 9):

use the following adb shell command:

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d
>   file:///storage/sdcard0/test.wav -t audio/wav

Comment: That is interesting. I ssh'd into the phone and tried. The command was recognized, but I got an android permission violation: `Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vocalf1.mp3 }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
...`

Comment: Adding --user 0 fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

There are two other command line programs which may work via a adb shell or even remotely using an ssh connection. Neither need an installed music player app.

```
adb shell stagefright -a -o file.mp3
```

and

```
adb shell tinyplay file.wav
```

(drop `adb shell` if not using an `adb` connection)

Note that `tinyplay` can only play stereo wav files. I found out about the `stagefright` command from [a3nm's blog: Android from the command-line](http://a3nm.net/blog/android_cli.html).

Comment: I get Unable to open file 'file.wav' error when using tinyplay. where the file should located?

Comment: That was just an example. You have to find or upload a file to play yourself.

Comment: I run `adb shell tinyplay  file:///storage/sdcard/download/bird.wav` but I got an error `Unable to open file 'file:///storage/sdcard/download/bird.wav'`. how I should address audio file?

Comment: Sorry! Now I understand. You need to use the unix path to the file, not a URL. `adb shell tinyplay /sdcard/download/bird.wav` will probably work, but it will depend on your device.