# ADB command to click on Play/Pause button when multiple music applications are installed in Android Phone

Tags: android, command, adb

When multiple music applications installed in android phone, When I click on Play/Pause button in one music application using adb command. It is clicking on some other music application in background and playing the music. How to resolve this?

I used below adb commands to click on Play/Pause button.

adb shell input keyevent 85

Comment: looks like `keyevent 85` is broadcasted through whole system, not in a single application.

Comment: How to make it work for foreground application using adb command?

Comment: you can try using `adb shell input touchscreen tap <X> <Y>` where `X` and `Y` are the coordinates fof pause button on the screen

Comment: Thank you so much. But, I am using different mobiles. So, X and Y coordinates will changes for each mobile. In this case can we use any other command using resource ID to perform Play/Pause Action?

Comment: you can calculate it based on screen size, etc. But in general - it is not a good way to go if you have multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably you miss this
[How can I play a mp3 file via adb command with google play music on android kitkat 4.4.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083848/how-can-i-play-a-mp3-file-via-adb-command-with-google-play-music-on-android-kitk)

To play

> adb shell input keyevent 126

To stop

> adb shell input keyevent 127

Comment: (adb shell input keyevent 126) is working for android 4.0 version but not above 4.0. Not sure why it is not working.

Comment: My phone version is 5.1, but it works.Have you seen this?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

Comment: I try this, and this work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829606/android-adb-stop-application-command-like-force-stop-for-non-rooted-device



adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>

Comment: Actually, I am working on 2 music applications which I have to test the scenarios:   1) to launch Google application -----> first play the song & Pause the song   ---------> closing the application.      2)      to launch Samsung application-----> Play song                 After launching the samsung application When I give keyevent 85 or 126, it is playing the first music applications song which is google music. But I want the song to play/pause in samsung which is foreground application. how to handle when two application need to launch and play song one after the other in Android 9.0?

Comment: Even after force-stop it is not working. Force-stop is working in 4.4.4 version but not on Android 9.0.  Any other command works here for Android version 9.0?

Answer (score 0):

To pause/play for both audio and video we can use both,

1. adb shell input keyevent 126
2. adb shell input keyevent 127

These are verified for **Android 9+** devices.